# Is it possible to send additional parameters when uploading a file in PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, html-post

I am initializing file upload using the following HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="PHPScripts/upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="browseButton" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

Upload.php script looks like this:

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES["image"];
$filepath = $file["name"];
$filetmp = $file["tmp_name"];
$filesize = $file["size"];
$filename = basename($filepath);
$filetype = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, ".") + 1);
...
?>
```

I need to pass one more parameter to my php script, but I don't know how. HTTP method is POST (as can be seen in the code above), but where should I put the parameter? Is that even possible? Thanks for clarifying this to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add another `input` element of your choice. No additional magic required.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="info" value="Test">
```

...

```
$info = $_POST["info"];
```

Comment: Is hidden secure? I can edit the info of hidden field and submit the form

Comment: @Who yes, it's possible to edit the info. You can never trust it if it comes from client side. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: If the info can be edited how hidden fields are useful? I am not getting from hidden field what I am using for

Comment: @WhoAmI anything can be manipulated on the client side. Always. `hidden` just doesn't show a control to the user, but there is no way to have an unchangeable parameter coming from client side. If you need to pass data that must not be altered by the client, use sessions instead

Comment: Thanks @Pekka I am always in doubt whether to use hidden or not I am still not in the favour of hidden Session is good in the case.

Comment: @WhoAmI so, use whatever else. What's the problem? If you have any question - start you own, but what's your point here, dude?

Comment: @Who it's unclear what the OP wants to do, so hidden may or may not be the solution - we can't tell really

Comment: use hidden and check it on the server side to make sure its what you want. fin!

Answer (score 0):

Just put one  element inside the same form where the file input is?